# How do I install all the requirements with npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, create-react-app

I would like to clone https://github.com/tstringer/create-react-app-with-redux and start a new project. I ran `npm start` and then ran `npm install` for each module not present, but there are many of them. Is there a way to install all the requirements? Something like `pip install -r requirements.txt` in Python.

Thanks,
Uri.

Comment: Yes. Just `npm install` without arguments.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you, it worked! if you want you can answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just run `npm install` without arguments. It will resolve the required dependencies from the `package.json` file.

Comment: Does `npm install <module>` also install everything from package.json if they were not already installed?

Answer (score 7):

It's simple.

If you want to install all the node_modules from the `package.json` file you simply put: `npm install` in terminal (on the same directory where the package.json exists) and it would install all the node modules in the folder called `node_modules`.

Generally, the `node_modules` folder is not uploaded in a git (by putting restriction at `.gitignore`) because it is essentially the same folders or packages that one would have to install, *hence installing it from `package.json` is simpler and it saves the internet bandwidth and time.

Even you want to save something in the package.json while you are installing any [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/) you can simply put `npm install --save your-package-name` and it would automatically save your package in the `.package.json` file and you can install the same file, even after you delete the `node_modules` folder using the same command.

Answer (score 5):

Better yet, if you want to save yourself a lot of time use `yarn install` instead of `npm install` (https://yarnpkg.com/en/). It is much faster because it caches everything and operates in parallel (see https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/ for a good comparison).

Answer (score 0):

npm install githubname/reponame -- Repository Name you can try

Answer (score 0):

npm audit fix --force . it will work . try this out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).